# Subsetting data.frame in R not changing regression results

Tags: r, subset

When I run a regression in R using lm I get an identical regression result when I use the original data.frame and when I subset the data.frame.

I have a data.frame in R with four years of data from around 250 different branches for a particular company.

I want to regress two variables over the whole four year span, and then regress over the individual years.

However, when I include a subset command to restrict the regression to a particular year, I do not get any errors and the regression is identical to the one over the entire four year span.

I have tried using several different subset methods and I have the same problem each time. I believe I am subsetting correctly because I am not getting any error messages and I can subset properly with these same commands in other circumstances.

Here is the regression I ran on the entire four-year span and the results:

```
> summary(lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
data = branch_annual))

Call:
lm(formula = branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
    data = branch_annual)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4815 -0.7767 -0.0109  0.8676  2.4406 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               1.67381    0.32745   5.112  4.3e-07 ***
branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup  0.22354    0.08323   2.686  0.00744 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.091 on 599 degrees of freedom
  (344 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0119,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.01025 
F-statistic: 7.214 on 1 and 599 DF,  p-value: 0.007435
```

I get the exact same result when I run the following command:

```
> summary(lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
data = subset(branch_annual, year == 15 )))
```

If I put 15 in quotation marks nothing changes.

I believe I am using the subset command correctly because if I run the following command:

```
> branch_annual_15 <- subset(branch_annual, year == 15)
```

It properly creates a data.frame that includes everything in branch_annual for which the column "year" has the value of 15, which is about one quarter of the data.frame.

If I run the original regression on this reduced data.frame I get a very different result.

Any ideas for what I might be missing and why the subset command is not changing anything when I run my regression?

Thanks!

Sebastian

Comment: Replace `branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale` with `Unfairness_Scale`, and same for `OS_EmpDSup`. As you've written it, it takes data from the `branch_annual` data frame, regardless of the `data` argument.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan thank you, that does solve that particular issue. 

However, I need to run many regressions in a loop. I am regressing about 20 different variables on branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale and I am referencing them in the loop by their column index (e.g. branch_annual[ , i]). 

So in the loop I need to still include the data.frame to reference different columns and I can't directly reference OS_EmpDSup. 

Any ideas for how I can solve this issue?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you might think.

First `split` the dataframe by `Year` and `Branch`, creating as many dataframes as there are combinations of those two columns' values.
Then run all regressions with `lapply` loops.

```
nms <- names(branch_annual)[-(1:3)]
sp <- split(branch_annual, list(branch_annual$Year, branch_annual$Branch))

lm_list <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  res <- lapply(nms, function(pred){
    fmla <- as.formula(paste("Y", pred, sep = "~"))
    lm(fmla, data = DF)
  })
  names(res) <- nms
  res
})

lm_list <- unlist(lm_list, recursive = FALSE)
```

Now use the list to get statistics of interess.
This will get the models' coefficients.

```
coef_list <- t(sapply(lm_list, coef))
colnames(coef_list)[2] <- "regressor"
```

Alternatively, compute the fitted models `summary`'s and from there extract the full data.frames with coefficients estimates, degrees of freedom, R squared, p-values etc.

```
smry_list <- lapply(lm_list, summary)

coef_list2 <- lapply(smry_list, '[[', "coefficients")
R2 <- sapply(smry_list, '[[', "r.squared")
```

**Test data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)

Branch <- sprintf("branch%03d", 1:250)
b <- length(Branch)
branch_annual <- data.frame(Year = rep(2015:2018, each = 5*b),
                            Branch = rep(Branch, 20))
m <- nrow(branch_annual)
Y <- runif(m, 0, 100)
preds <- matrix(runif(m*7, 0, 100), nrow = m)
colnames(preds) <- LETTERS[1:7]
branch_annual <- cbind(branch_annual, Y, preds)
```

Comment: Hi Rui Barradas,

Thank you for your response.

I think this will work if I wanted to regress the same variable each time. 

However, I will need to change the variable every time, so I can't simply put "OS_EmpDSup". 

I would like to find a way to reference the column of the data frame there. Currently I do "branch_annual[, a] in a for loop where a increases each iteration.

How can I iterate through the variables without specifically referencing the data.frame, as that defeats the purpose of subsetting?

Thanks, 

Sebastian

Comment: @Sebastian Now I don't understand. You want to regress several variables, each of them a separate regression per each year?

Comment: Hi Rui Barradas, 

I apologize if I am not being clear. 

Suppose I have dependent variable Y and independent variables A-G in a data.frame that has 250 branches and four years of observation (2016, 2016, 2017, 2018). I want to run separate regressions of:

Y ~ A, 
Y ~ B, 
Y ~ C, 

and so on. And I want to do all of these regressions in 2015 only, then in 2016 only, 2017 only, and 2018 only. 

If I don't want to write "branch_annual[ , column #], how can I reference the specific variables without writing the data.frame in the formula?

Thanks,

Comment: @Sebastian Code completely changed. See if this is it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to explicit the regression by doing:

```
lmFull <- lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
data = branch_annual)
lmSub <- lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
data = subset(branch_annual, year == 15 ))
lmSubBis <- lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_EmpDSup, 
data = branch_annual[branch_annual$year == 15,])
```

and then execute the compare

```
summary(lmFull)
summary(lmSub)
summary(lmSubBis)
```

The outputs still the same?

Comment: Yes -- I have the same issue.

Comment: Yep--nothing different still